# Custom "View Item" Button

Tags: custom-list, view

I want to create a custom `View Item` button similar to the `Edit Item` button, without the use of SharePoint Designer?
Can anyone guide me to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

**Note:**

in June 2017, Microsoft disabled the use of JavaScript in a Calculated Column

That means given answers may not apply  for newer SharePoint versions

For long explanation and work arounds see:
[June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

---

**Original answer:**

- Create a Calculated Column `View`
- set Datatype=Number (will output String as HTML)
- Add the Formula:

  ```
    ="<a href='#' onclick=""{event.stopPropagation();"
    &"var ID=getItemIDFromIID(findIIDInAncestorNode(this)),"
    &"url=_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath.replace(/[^\/]*$/gi,'');"
    &"this.parentNode.innerHTML='Opening:'+ID;"
    &"document.location=url+'DispForm.aspx?ID='+ID;"
    &"}""><img src='/_layouts/images/VIEWREPORTSHH.png' width='20px'></a>"
  ```

Onclick it captures the ID value from the TR node
Builts the correct url
Displays a message (every click in a webpage should give an immediate response IMHO)
goes to the url

*I am not 100% sure if those IID functions exist in 2010, if not see the examples below for alternative code*

More:

- Clone/Duplicate item: [Set default values in new controls on custom form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154597/set-default-values-in-new-controls-on-custom-form/154603#154603)
- Start a Workflow: [Can I add a start workflow link to a column in a list view?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150787/can-i-add-a-start-workflow-link-to-a-column-in-a-list-view/150796#150796)

ICC