# Is it possible to have a button inside a column in Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to have a button inside a column in Sharepoint list.

For Example:

We have a column as ID - number, Name - Single line text box, Status - Approve as button so that user will click Approve and will update the Field value in the list and submits the record.

Is it is feasible in Sharepoint.

Comment: May I know, which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint Online, you can take advantage of JSLink to render your Status field as you want - in this case a button with some javascript logic behind it.

The process would be very similar to the one described here: http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/using-jslink-to-implement-delete-buttons-for-list-view.

I'm assuming here that by "submits the record" you are referring to something that can be achieved by javascript

Answer (score 3):

**Note:**

in June 2017, Microsoft disabled the use of JavaScript in a Calculated Column

That means given answers may not apply  for newer SharePoint versions

For long explanation and work arounds see:
[June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

---

**Original answer:**

- Create a Calculated Column `View`
- set Datatype=Number (will output String as HTML)
- Add the Formula:

  ```
    ="<a href='#' onclick=""{event.stopPropagation();"
    &"var ID=getItemIDFromIID(findIIDInAncestorNode(this)),"
    &"url=_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath.replace(/[^\/]*$/gi,'');"
    &"this.parentNode.innerHTML='Opening:'+ID;"
    &"document.location=url+'DispForm.aspx?ID='+ID;"
    &"}""><img src='/_layouts/images/VIEWREPORTSHH.png' width='20px'></a>"
  ```

Onclick it captures the ID value from the TR node
Builts the correct url
Displays a message (every click in a webpage should give an immediate response IMHO)
goes to the url

*I am not 100% sure if those IID functions exist in 2010, if not see the examples below for alternative code*

More:

- Clone/Duplicate item: [Set default values in new controls on custom form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154597/set-default-values-in-new-controls-on-custom-form/154603#154603)
- Start a Workflow: [Can I add a start workflow link to a column in a list view?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150787/can-i-add-a-start-workflow-link-to-a-column-in-a-list-view/150796#150796)

ICC

Comment: To get the calculated field working on new webapps you need to change a property:  
  
`$url = "http://yourwebappurl"  
$spWA = Get-SPWebApplication $url  
$spWA.CustomMarkupInCalculatedFieldDisabled = $false  
$spWA.Update()`

Answer (score 0):

The column formatting is handled in this document: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Here is an example of adding a button into the list. This can connect to a **Power Automate** flow which can handle the approval.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "It's Flow Time!",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\":\"f7ecec0b-15c5-419f-8211-302a5d4e94f1\", \"headerText\":\"It's Flow Time!\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Do it\"}"
  }
}
```